# Prevent connection of BLE device to GATT server

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

Third party BLE device has attempt to connect to my GATT server, the result is that device become inaccessible for his native app. My wild guess is I should prevent connection of that device to my GATT server, but I don't know how to do that. Any suggestion? Thanx

Comment: I have the idea to disconnect unknown device `cancelConnection(BluetoothDevice device)` right after `onConnectionStateChange` recieved with it is has connnected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision was not so trivial: it is necessary to clear any links to previously discovered (scanned) BLE devices by `onLeScan` when app goes to background (`onPause` received, but still not `onDestroy`). If you still keeping these links, you'll unable to connect to those devices from other app.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your GATT server with a White List of devices that you wish to accept connections from. That way it will not accept connections from any 3rd party devices.

Comment: But how can I do that?)